# Can I show that I'll not retaliate upon negative feedback? Am I being trolled/harassed?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, feedback, trolling

Within the last year or two (* see correction), when I post a question on the various Stack Exchange sites, it usually gets a downvote within about two minutes. At first I thought I was somehow unknowingly posting poor questions, or missing some cultural taboo. The consistency of this, however, is starting to make me suspicious.

(* It has been more than two years; I practically stopped posting questions after I noticed the trend in 2018. Time has seemed so strange recently.)

The downvotes come with no comment. Comments, answers, and a few upvotes usually come later, fortunately. At first I was surprised that the downvotes were coming with no suggestions on how to improve, until my research into how to resolve this revealed that a comment with a downvote can result in vengeful actions from an OP. I'm glad to see discussion about how to improve this issue of downvotes sometimes being only hurtful (decrease in reputation) rather than actually being feedback.

Is there some way to figure out if someone is trolling/harassing me?

Is it pretty common for new questions to be downvoted for no reason, just as a matter of course?

Is there any stylistic issue, missing information, taboo communication, etc. within this post which would warrant a downvote?

Is there some way that I can show that I'll not retaliate if someone gives me written negative feedback on a question?

**My most recent examples:**

- *[Permanent redirect removal of file extensions in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690012/permanent-redirect-removal-of-file-extensions-in-url)* This was the straw that broke the camel's back; I practically stopped posting questions after this. The comment linking to another question sort of looks like it's the same, but it isn't; and the answers only apply to a redirect for a single specified file, rather than all files of a particular extension.
- *[How to restore from a sealed APFS volume when restore fails "because it has a broken seal"](https://superuser.com/questions/1621977/restoring-sealed-apfs-volume-fails-because-it-has-a-broken-seal)*

Comment: Commenting something along the lines of "I'd appreciate any suggestions on how the question/answer can be improved." is fine. Don't specifically ask about the reason for the downvote(s) though because that's usually frowned upon by most users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there some way to figure out if someone is trolling/harassing me?

You could flag for moderator attention and ask.  Moderators can see if an account has been systematically downvoted by another account (at least on a single site).  However, in your case, it seems unlikely.  Unless you've been deleting your questions after asking them, you've only posted two questions other than this one in the past two years (and this one hasn't, as of yet, been downvoted).  Two posts that got downvoted is hardly a pattern.

> Is it pretty common for new questions to be downvoted for no reason, just as a matter of course?

Not usually, but it's not unheard of.  Usually, if well asked, it's because it's a common question that someone's sick of seeing asked.  In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55970091/208273), based on the comments, I would guess you were downvoted for reasons along those lines.

> Is there any stylistic issue, missing information, taboo communication, etc. within this post which would warrant a downvote? Would it be helpful for me to link to my other Stack Exchange profiles for examples of my style in other questions I've asked?

Examples would be helpful, and would save people the trouble of digging through your network profile to find the (very few) posts that you've posted in the specified time period to see examples of what you're talking about.

> Is there some way that I can show that I'll not retaliate if someone gives me written negative feedback on a question?

I'd echo [41686d6564's excellent suggestion from the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360312/can-i-show-that-ill-not-retaliate-upon-negative-feedback-am-i-being-trolled-ha#comment1202423_360312) here:

> Commenting something along the lines of "I'd appreciate any suggestions on how the question/answer can be improved." is fine. Don't specifically ask about the reason for the downvote(s) though because that's usually frowned upon by most users.

This is excellent advice.  Don't mention downvotes; just mention your desire to improve the post.  I've used this in the past myself to get feedback that turned a negatively voted answer into a positively voted one.  Getting into arguments in the comments or saying things like "Obviously..." (to use an example from the above linked post) will only result in more downvotes, if anything (I note that you apologized for the tone later, which was good, though).

Comment: Thank you. I did stop posting questions some time ago because of the downvotes, I didn't realize that was more than two years ago.